# Url rewriting with .htaccess issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Url rewriting doesn't seem to work.
I want to rewrite `http://www.domainname.com/job.php?id=41` to `job.php/41`

So this is the code I wrote in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine 
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ job.php?/$1 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ job.php?/$1
```

Doesn't seem to work. Anyone having a idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
ReWriteRule ^job.php/(.*?) job.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer but it doesn't seem to work. Could it be because I'm working on a localhost?

Comment: Correction. It works, had to save my file with the ANSI encoding.